# No Valid Data Send Error - During export products via System->import/Export->Export

Tags: magento-1.9, error, export, timeout, delivery-time

I get error like "No Valid Data Send Error" during export products via System->import/Export->Export. Actually this is memory problem may be, how can i solve this error.

Note : **Duplicate Finder** - There is no proper solution all over Stackover Flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes directly from the method **exportAction()** from **Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController** class:

```
public function exportAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
            /** @var $model Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export */
            $model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
            $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());

            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                $model->getContentType()
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
    }
    return $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

So, check the **var/log/exception.log**, maybe you can see more information about the error.

Comment: there is no exception in exception log file,

Comment: and the path : Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController  not in my root folder,  its like app_code_core_mege_ImportExport (block,controllers,etc,helper,model,sql)  thats all. How can i solve my error.